# How i fill and remove dynamically dict for widget?

Tags: python, qt, signals-slots, qlineedit, qcheckbox

I have the following code:

```
#####   Slots for checkboxes (enable/disabling)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox_3, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged(int)")), self.checkBox_3.setOn)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox_3, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged(int)")), self.dateEdit.setEnabled)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox_3, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged(int)")), self.dateEdit_2.setEnabled)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged(int)")), self.lineEdit.setEnabled)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged(int)")), self.lineEdit_2.setEnabled)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox_4, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged(int)")), self.lineEdit_3.setEnabled)
#####

##### Slots for checkboxes/lineEdits (filling dict for database fields and values)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged(int)")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.setFilterDict(self,"name",self.lineEdit.text()))
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged(int)")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.setFilterDict(self,"bought_price",persianToInteger(unicode(self.lineEdit_2.text()))))
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox_3, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged(int)")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.setFilterDict(self,"bought_date",self.dateEdit.text())) ##date        
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox_4, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged(int)")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.setFilterDict(self,"stock",persianToInteger(unicode(self.lineEdit_3.text()))))        


QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("editingFinished()")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.responseToRequestForData(self))
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("editingFinished()")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.responseToRequestForData(self))
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.dateEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("editingFinished()")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.responseToRequestForData(self))         
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit_3, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("editingFinished()")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.responseToRequestForData(self))        



#### pressing seach key and start search action
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("returnPressed()")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.responseToRequestForData(self))
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButtonSearch, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.responseToRequestForData(self))
#######



##    enable/disabling "price date" checkbox
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox_3, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("toggled(bool)")), self.dateEdit.setEnabled)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.checkBox_3, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("toggled(bool)")), self.dateEdit_2.setEnabled)
```

Then i have the following `SLOT` in  another file:

```
def setFilterDict(self,obj,field,lineEditContent):
    self.objectSearchMaterials = obj

    if field not in self.filterNameDict.keys():# and self.filterNameDict.values() is not None:
        self.filterNameDict.update({field:lineEditContent})
    else:
        del self.filterNameDict[field]
```

**My question** is , When i click on `checkboxes`, i fill a dict with a text : `self.filterNameDict` , But when i click for more of once, it can't handle the given dict.How i create a dynamically dict for handle every `checkboxes`? It means i need to when i click to a `checkbox` add name of fieald and `lineEdit text()` to dict and When i remove it , automatically remove from dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `self.filterNameDict.pop(field, None)` instead of `del self.filterNameDict[field]`.

Help:

```
>>> help(dict.pop)
Help on method_descriptor:

pop(...)
    D.pop(k[,d]) -> v, remove specified key and return the corresponding value.
    If key is not found, d is returned if given, otherwise KeyError is raised
```